# R: Scraping dynamic dropdown menus (rvest, httr)

Tags: r

I've done a little bit of web scraping previously, but I'm very much a beginner when it comes to HTML and XML structures.

On the following website (https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/calculators/swh-stc-calculator) there is a form with the following fields:

- System brand
- System model
- Installation date
- Postcode
- Disclaimer check box

And then a 'calculate' button to generate results

The first two fields are drop down boxes, the second box (system model) changes dynamically based on the system brand input.

What I would like to do is extract a list of all **system brand** options (~130), then for each brand extract all associated **system models**, and iteratively enter fixed values for the installation date and postcode and return the values generated by the calculator.

I can hunt down the XPATH of the system brands (`//*[@id="refSystemBrand"]`) - but I've tried extracting a list of system brands via `rvest::html_element` but it yields an empty list.

Based on some similar SO questions, I suspect I might need to use `httr::POST()` to drive the form entry (or the `httr::html_form_` functions?). But I genuinely have no idea where to start with these functions (and I don't find the help or intro tutorials very enlightening).

Any help on what I'm doing wrong, or the bits that I clearly don't understand about how web forms are designed would be very appreciated!

Comment: Brand options are available here - `jsonlite::fromJSON('https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/calculators/swh/stc/reference-data?_=1630556062240')$brand`

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, how did you navigate to that url?

Comment: And the associated models for each brand can be navigated to here: `jsonlite::fromJSON('https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/calculators/swh/stc/reference-data-model?brandName=AAE%20Solar')$models`

Comment: Open the selector tools, go to Network tab, refreshed the page and looked for json urls there.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I still don't really understand how the front-facing web page and the JSON layer where data is stored fit together, but this is helpful for sourcing the brand and model lists.

Comment: FWIW I got a working solution together based on RSelenium. It's a bit temperamental, but it works well enough (for now).

Answer (score 0):

A basic way of getting what you want is inserting the resulting combinations from your lists into the following post request.

```
require(httr)
library(tidyverse)


headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
`Email` = 'add your email to be transparent'
)

data = '{"postcode":"3000","systemBrand":"AAE Solar","systemModel":"ES-250E-30-S26M","installationDate":"2021-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"}'

res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://www.rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/calculators/swh/stc', 
                  body = data, 
                  add_headers(headers),
                  verbose())
```

Comment: Thanks @Datapumpernickel - this approach works really well for one or two requests, but I'm getting the dreaded `curl_fetch_memory` error pretty consistently when running it in a loop - I haven't seen any good solutions online for addressing this. 
I've got a working solution based on RSeleneium, it's a bit slow and a bit temperamental, but it's functioning.